# ASP.NET datetime mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core

I run into a problem when asp.net maps value of `<input type="date" />`.

Rendered value looks like `Fri Nov 11 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0300`.

When I get it into my MVC controller, it turns into `10.11.2011 21:00:00`.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: AFAIK, JS tends to keep your current timezone where C# interpret it as UTC date when doing ajax call/postback, hence inserted time will subtracted by 3 hours. Use `toISOString()` for converting JS format to UTC and followed by `DateTime.AddHours(3)` on posted date may solve your issue.

Comment: It doesn't look like good solution.

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.ParseExact` and `String.Format`? You can define custom formatting as you want to represent any date, like `ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz` to produce time format string exactly like JS does.

Comment: I have a mapped datetime value. I don't have a string.

Comment: I resolve it by using `toLocaleDateString()`